# Do Chef environments follow cookbook dependencies?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

1. I have 2 cookbooks **A** and **B**
2. They each have 2 versions V1 and V2
3. In the metadata.rb of cookbook **A** I have `depends
   'B', '=V2'`
4. I have an env named **ENV1** that has V1 of cookbook **B** pinned

Now for nodes assigned to **ENV1** that use cookbook **A** will they respected the version of cookbook **B** pinned in **ENV1** (V1) or will they use the version specified in cookbook **A's** metadata file (V2).

Basically just want to know that if I pin a version of a cookbook in an env there is no way any nodes assigned the env can use a different version.

Comment: If the version comparison is =, you'll have a failure of dependency resolution as it can't satisfy the two constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the relevant constraints get considered. So the environment a node is in are absolute constraints (they must be fulfilled), and the constraints on each available cookbook version are exposed to the solver. It will attempt to find a set of cookbook versions that have mutually valid constraints. If it fails to find one, you will get an error.